# MongooseError: Query was already executed: Error: Discord.js

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

**Code**

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");


client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
    const chatbots = require("./All-Commands-Schemas/ChatbotSchema")
    await chatbots.findOne({ guild: message.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
        if (!data) return;
        if (err) throw err
        const channell = data.channel
        if (message.author.bot || message.channel.type === 'dm') return;

        if (message.channel.id === channell) {
            message.channel.sendTyping();
            await fetch(`http://api.brainshop.ai/get?bid=163&key=rztKzYO&uid=${message.author.id}&msg=${message.content}`)
                .then(cnt => cnt.json())
                .then(data => {
                    message.channel.send(data.cnt);
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    message.channel.send("Couldn't fetch response!");
                })
        };
    });
});
```

**Error**

```
Reason: MongooseError: Query was already executed: chatbots.findOne(
```

Hi I need help with the following error and code which is provided above. Below are the versions of my code.

"mongoose": "^6.1.6",
"discord.js": "^13.3.1",
"node": "16.13.2",
"npm": "8.1.2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use await and callback in same query, you should remove await

```
chatbots.findOne({ guild: message.guild.id }, async (err, data) => {
//do some thing
}
```

or callback

```
const data = awaitchatbots.findOne({ guild: message.guild.id })
//do something
```